# Not sure what is causing the index error in my if statement

Tags: python, arrays, runtime-error

I am writing code for a black box test for an assignment.  In my function the inputs are a 2d array, and int for x, and int for y, and an int for zombie strength.  From my start position if the value of the element is less than the zombie strength, I change the value of the element to -1.  Than I got to that elements neighbors, up, down, left, and right (Not diagonal) and do the same to them.  I am using a try except, if the element exists than add it to a list, if not move on.  From what I understand using a try except will stop from adding element that do not exist in the array in the list.  That is why I am not sure why I am getting an indexing error when I black box test my code.  The inputs I added, but I do not know what inputs the black box test is using.

```
Here is my code 
population = [[9, 3, 4, 5, 4], [1, 6, 5, 8, 9], [2, 3, 7, 3, 2], [4,5,1,4,3], [4, 5, 4, 3, 9]]
x = 2
y = 1
zombie = 5



def answer(population, x, y, zombie):
    list = []
    list.append([x,y])
    while list:
        print list
        front_of_list = list.pop(0)
        x = front_of_list[0]
        y = front_of_list[1]
        if population[front_of_list[0]][front_of_list[1]] <= zombie and population[front_of_list[0]][front_of_list[1]] >= 0:
            population[front_of_list[0]][front_of_list[1]] =  -1
            if x-1 >=0:
                try:
                    population[x-1][y]
                    list.append([x-1,y])
                except:
                    pass
            if y-1 >= 0:
                try:
                    population[x][y-1]
                    list.append([x,y-1])
                except:
                    pass
            if x+1 < len(population):
                try:
                    population[x+1][y]
                    list.append([x+1,y])
                except:
                    pass
            if y+1 < len(population[0]):
                try:
                    population[x][y+1]
                    list.append([x,y+1])
                except:
                    pass



answer(population, x, y, zombie)
print population
```

Comment: Which line is getting the error?

Comment: copy and paste the complete traceback in your question

Comment: I just ran your code with python 2.7 and it ran fine

Comment: @Barmar line 9 is giving me the error, it is the only if statement in my code

Comment: There are 5 `if` statements in your code. `if x - 1 >= 0:`, `if y-1 >= 0:`, etc.

Comment: None of the `if` statements are inside a `try` block, so why would you expect that to prevent errors?

Comment: @Aaron and line 9 is hard to read. With complex code showing sublte problems I find it often helpful to add perfect code formatting / indentation to make it easier to spot the bug

Comment: Several people have not hit an error with this code... Are you actually using the exact same code and data when you hit you error?

Answer (score 0):

Your `try` clauses aren't necessary as the `if` test you do before covers the situation.  Let's try simplifying and clarifying the code to see if that fixes your problem since we're unable to reproduce it directly.

First, you continue to use `front_of_list` when `x` and `y` will do; we can simplify the `if` clauses by combining the tests (a Python feature); the `(x, y)` are naturally tuples so I switched them; you redefined the built-in name `list` so I switched it to `array`; finally I reduced the tests to loops to reduce the chance of copy-n-paste errors.  This leaves us with:

```
def answer(population, x, y, zombie):
    array = [(x, y)]

    x_limit = len(population)
    y_limit = len(population[0])

    while array:
        print array
        x, y = array.pop(0)

        if 0 <= population[x][y] <= zombie:

            population[x][y] = -1

            for dx in (-1, 1):
                if 0 <= x + dx < x_limit:
                    array.append((x + dx, y))

            for dy in (-1, 1):
                if 0 <= y + dy < y_limit:
                    array.append((x, y + dy))

population = [
    [9, 3, 4, 5, 4],
    [1, 6, 5, 8, 9],
    [2, 3, 7, 3, 2],
    [4, 5, 1, 4, 3],
    [4, 5, 4, 3, 9]
    ]

x, y = 2, 1

zombie = 5

answer(population, x, y, zombie)

print population
```

Plug this into your test situation and pass along the exact error messages if it continues to fail.

Your code and this assume a rectangular matrix, if your 2D array is ragged, this will cause an indexing error.  (Something to double check.)

**UPDATE**

The traditional sense of x is *columns* and y is *rows* but your code (and my rework) has this reversed.  Internally, it makes no difference but since you are being passed x & y as arguments, from the perspective of the code yours plugs into, this might mean the starting point is incorrect and might cause it to invalidate your result.  (Again, something to double check.)